# In Microsoft Access, what is a faster way to run the equivalent of a query with a JOIN expression that uses a TRIM function?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query to join 2 tables with fields consisting of email addresses, but one table (incoming data) often has leading or trailing spaces, and I have to keep the original data as is, but else where in the application I have to show which records don't match without regard for the leading or trailing spaces. So I wrote a query using the TRIM function in the JOIN, but it's incredibly slow.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON TRIM(Table1.Email) = TRIM(Table2.Email)
```

In addition, both tables are linked text files, and have to be linked that way, as the manager insists that we verify our results by directly comparing the original incoming data to our processed outgoing data.

Does anyone know a better and more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: It seems like you already removed most options for improvement. I'd say: import the tables, trim them, add indexes, and then run heavy queries. If you leave them as text files, it's never going to be fast. If you run all those steps, it's probably faster than running your query once.

Comment: No indexes on text files.  Do you really need the trim on both sides?  aside from loading them and creating indexes I can't see how this gets faster.

Comment: *"manager insists that we verify our results by directly comparing the original incoming data to our processed outgoing data"* - I don't see how that requirement would prohibit importing the data into a usable form as an intermediate step. As others have stated, continuing to work with linked text files is almost certainly going to slow you down.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling I may have to add steps to import the text files into temporary tables and do the query on those. I just thought there might be a simpler, easier way. But I wasn't counting on it!